# Opening a file on a local server

Tags: java, sockets, url, networking, io

I'm trying to open a file located on a local server.

```
        String stringIds = "";
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.181/file.txt");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringIds += line;
        }
```

But the line:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

doesn't work (the `conn.getInputStream()` fails). I can open the file in Chrome.

Comment: What does _doesn't work_ and _fails_ mean?

Comment: Does that url ("http://192.168.1.181/file.txt") work in your browser? It's clearly a local IP, so you need to check from your local server.

Comment: Works fine on my computer. What error do you get? Can you copy-paste it here, please?

Comment: I have a java.nio.BufferOverflowException exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because my file had no extension, so I add .txt, like in my exemple and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String content = new URL("http://192.168.1.181/file.txt").getContent();
```

Comment: Tried, same problem.
My file contains only some json, it has no headers. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: No headers are ok. It is important that the server returns `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` and two newlines before the file starts.